# how to label usb as bootable?

Tags: boot, usb, windows

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 USB disk. It was bootable. But I accidentally labeled it as not bootable (unchecked bootable) from Ubuntu demo desktop.
Now I am using Windows.but I want to label USB as bootable, or any way to run the Ubuntu installation.
I not have another iso file of ubuntu

Comment: You can download it again: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: If UEFI, you have to have the FAT32 partition with the boot flag. You can add that with gparted, choose partition and right click for flags. If a BIOS boot, then you add the boot flag. Syslinux & Windows use boot flag, but grub does not need a flag.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend downloading a new version of Ubuntu, and downloading Rufus. Rufus creates bootable USB sticks with whatever ISO you put on it. You get to choose whether or not it is bootable, and it will format the stick for you before hand. There is not another way to run the installer from the USB that I am aware of. If you can get a new ISO this would be the way to go, then you have the newest version on your USB stick.